# Contour integration around pole and essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I've got the following integral:

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\limits{|z|\,=\,R} \frac{z^5}{z-1} e^\frac{2}{z} dz,
$$

where $R$ - sufficiently large number.

I've tried to evaluate it with residues. The integrand has a simple pole at $z = 1$ and an essential singularity at $z=0$.

Evaluation of the residue about the pole is trivial: it equals to $e^2$. I tried to deal with the singularity:

$$
\frac{z^5}{z-1} e^\frac{2}{z} = z^4 \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}} e^\frac{2}{z} = \left[z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1 + \frac{1}{z} + ... \right]\left[1 + \frac{2}{z} + \frac{2}{z^2} + \frac{4}{3z^3} + \frac{2}{3z^4} + \frac{4}{15z^5} + ... \right].
$$

After term-by-term multiplication and collecting terms with $\frac{1}{z}$ I got the residue $\frac{109}{15}$. Therefore, the integral equals to $e^2 + \frac{109}{15}$.

But I am told it's wrong, and I can't find a problem for a long time. Can someone tell, is that solution wrong? Very grateful in advance for your help and time. Thanks!

Comment: $z^4 + z^3 + \ldots$ is the Laurent expansion of $z^5/(z - 1)$ around infinity (on $|z| > 1$). You've found the coefficient at $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion of $f(z) = z^5 e^{2/z}/(z - 1)$ around infinity, which is equal to minus the residue of $f(z)$ at infinity and is also equal to $\int_{|z| = R} f(z) \, dz/(2 \pi i)$.

Comment: @Maxim, is that so... I had thoughts of expanding the function around infinity, but confused myself with around what am I expanding. Thank you for your clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors. A minor one is that you forgot to divide the residue by $2\pi i$. And a major one is that, near $0$, you have$$\frac{z^5}{z-1}=-z^5 - z^6 - z^7 -\cdots$$instead of$$\frac{z^5}{z-1}=z^4+z^3+z^2+\cdots$$

Comment: I was afraid to use $\frac{1}{1-z}$ because of infinite sum for the coefficient before $\frac{1}{z}$ and at the same time thought that it's legal to use $\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}$ about zero. Or is it, after all? Still confused, as a matter of fact.

Thank you very much for your help, I've managed to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{R\ \mbox{is a}\ \underline{\it sufficiently\ large\ number}}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{{1 \over 2\pi\ic}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ R}\,\,\,
{z^{5} \over z - 1}\expo{2/z}\,\dd z}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{z\ \mapsto\ 1/z}{=}\,\,\,&
{1 \over 2\pi\ic}\bracks{%
-\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1/R}\,\,\,
{1/z^{5} \over 1/z - 1}\expo{2z}
\,\pars{-\,{\dd z \over z^{2}}}}
\\[5mm] = &
{1 \over 2\pi\ic}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1/R}\,\,\,
{\expo{2z} \over z^{6}\pars{1 - z}}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &
{1 \over 2\pi\ic}\bracks{2\pi\ic\,{1 \over \pars{6 - 1}!}
\,\lim_{z \to 0}\,\,\totald[5]{}{z}
\bracks{z^{6}\,{\expo{2z} \over z^{6}\pars{1 - z}}}}
\\[5mm] = &
{1 \over 120}
\,\ \underbrace{\lim_{z \to 0}\,\,\totald[5]{}{z}
\pars{{\expo{2z} \over 1 - z}}}_{\ds{872}}\ =\
\bbx{109 \over 15} \approx 7.2667
\end{align}

Comment: Dear God, how easy that was... I was confident I'll have to use residuals, and nothing more will fit. Thanks a lot!